# null value in dictionary keys that is never inserted

Tags: c#, dictionary

In the following code i inserted some dummy code to check for null and remove them just to try understand what is goign on. I still do not get why my problem happens :)

I have the following that inserts values into a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, DateTimeOffset> _keys = new Dictionary<string, DateTimeOffset>();
public async Task NotifyAsync(DateTimeOffset key)
{
    if (key==null)
    {
        this._logger.LogError("Recieved null key");
        return;
    }
    var dictKey = RadarContext.TrimTimeToPartitionBin(key, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dictKey))
    {
        this._logger.LogError("Recieved null dictKey for {time}",key);
        return;
    }

    _keys[dictKey] = key;
    await this.SetLastUpdatedAsync(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
}
```

Nothing else inserts.

Then i have the following that loops over the keys later

```
foreach(var key in _keys.Keys.Where(k => string.IsNullOrEmpty( k )).ToArray())
{
    _logger.LogError("Removed null key: {time}",_keys[key]);
    _keys.Remove(key);
}

foreach (var key in _keys.Keys.OrderByDescending(key=> RadarContext.FromTrim(key,_logger)).Take(100).ToArray())
{
    if (_keys[key] < tminus1)
    {
        await actionblock.SendAsync(key);
    }
}
```

and my problem is that i get an null exception in `RadarContext.FromTrim`

```
public static DateTimeOffset FromTrim(string trim, ILogger  logger = null)
{
    try
    {
        var ticks = long.Parse(trim);
        return new DateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset.MaxValue.UtcTicks - ticks, TimeSpan.Zero);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if (logger != null)
            logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to convert from {trim}", trim);

        throw;
    }
}
```

and the error is as follows:

```
2019-03-05 23:15:21.922 +01:00 [ERR] Failed to convert from null
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
   at System.Int64.Parse(String s)
   at Ascend.Wammo.RadarIngestor.ServiceProvider.RadarContext.FromTrim(String trim, ILogger logger) in C:\dev\AscendXYZ\Ascend.Wammo.RadarIngestor\apps\Ascend.Wammo.RadarIngestor.ServiceProvider\RadarContext.cs:line 493
```

How is it possible with the given code here that FromTrim is given a null when looping over `_keys.Keys.OrderByDescending(key=> RadarContext.FromTrim(key,_logger))` when a null is never inserted.

Comment: Are you using the dictionary in multiple threads? If so, `Dictionary<,>` isn't safe for use that way - that could explain it, potentially.

Comment: You are right, thats the case. The inserting and loop is running on two different threads.

Comment: Right - I suggest you use `ConcurrentDictionary` then.

Comment: @Jon could please put your comments (ie the solution) as an answer. *Sorry I've got OCD (obsessive comments disorder)*

Comment: @JeremyThompson: To be honest it doesn't feel like it's worth of leaving as an answer, but I'll do so...

Comment: @JonSkeet I can do it for you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` from multiple threads, which it's not intended for. Presumably some modification of the internal state in one thread is leading to seeing a null key in the other thread.

`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` *is* intended for use in multiple threads - but I would still avoid using it in *quite* the way you're doing at the moment. Right now, you're iterating over the keys and doing a lookup for each key separately. I would loop over the *entries* instead:

```
var entries = _keys
    .OrderByDescending(entry => RadarContext.FromTrim(entry.Key, _logger))
    .Take(100)
    .ToArray();

foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    if (entry.Value < tminus1)
    {
        await actionblock.SendAsync(entry.Key);
    }
}
```

That way you get a consistent snapshot.